# trying to understand this profile lookup in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I am having some issues understanding this challenge from FreeCodeCamp< i just did all the steps that I was told to do on the challange but I can just get it to work, here is the link

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup

And here is my solution

```
// Setup
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for ( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

if (contacts[i].firstName == name)
{
    if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
         
    return contacts[i][prop]
} else if (!contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    return  "No such property"
} 
} else {
    return  "No such contact"
}

} 

// Only change code above this line
}


lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I am trying to call the function by using lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes") and I should get ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"], but instead I am getting "No such contact"

Comment: Why do you downvote this question?It normal for someone to not understant what is asked and he has also provide what he has tied to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing my solution which is slightly different from yours. Compare it to your own. You will see that I only return inside my for loop when I get a positive match , otherwise I let the loop run. This is the biggest difference.
You need to let the loop run fully and then through some mechanism keep track of the missing conditions . I have used two different variables to track the missing conditions here.

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
   let hasNoName = true;
   let hasNoProp = true;
   for( let i = 0 ; i < contacts.length; i++){
       const contact = contacts[i];
       if( contact['firstName'] === name ){
           hasNoName = false;
           if( contact[prop]){
               hasNoProp = false;
               return contact[prop];
           }
       }
   }
   if( hasNoName ) return "No such contact";
   if( hasNoProp ) return "No such property";
// Only change code above this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me explain the problem step by step and how i solve it.

You are given an array of objects where each object contained in the array represents a contact.

Each contact has some data that is stored , so there is a `First name` represented by the attributes `firstName`,the `last name` by the attribut `lastName`, a `number` reprented by the attribute `number` and the last attribute is `likes`.Each attribute contains some data about the contact,so all the contacts have the same attributes but with different values.

What you're asked is to implement a function that takes to attributes : `name` and `prop`.remember that each object has a `name` but, separated in `firstName` and `lastName`.If the `name` parametre passed in your fonction verifies `either` the `lastName attribute` or the `firstName` attribute, it means that the user exist.In another words, the `name` parameter will be compared with the `firstName` if, there are equal, it means that the user exist, otherwise it will be also compared with the `lastName` is they are equal, it means that the user exist, so  for that user, the function shoul return the value the attributes whos name matches the `prop` parameter.

Here is the code:

```
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line

//Checking whether the name parametre is equal either to the contacts firstName
// or lastName attributes
for(let contact of contacts){
    if(name===contact["firstName"] || name===contact["lastName"]){

        //Here i check if the attrbute prop exist in the object 
        if(contact[prop]){
            return contact[prop];//it return the value of that attribute if it exists
        }else{
            return "No such property" //The string that i return if it doesn't exist
        }
    }
}
return "No such contact"
// Only change code above this line
}
```

Notice : I've used the `for of loop from ES6`, but the same code with the a traditionnale for loop would be :

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
// Only change code below this line
for(let i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if(name===contacts[i]["firstName"] || name===contacts[i]["lastName"]){
        if(contacts[i][prop]){
            return contacts[i][prop];
        }else{
            return "No such property"
        }
    }
}
return "No such contact"
// Only change code above this line
}
```